# PHP to consume webservice that needs xs:base64Binary

Tags: php, web-services

I've got a webservice which expects a parameter of type "xs:base64Binary" - this is a file to store in the database.

I'm trying to consume the service using PHP 5's native webservice classes. I've tried a few things:

```
// Get the posted file
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);

// Add the file, encoding it as a base64
$parameters = array("fileBytes" => base64_encode($file));

// Call the webservice
$response = $client->attachFile($parameters);
```

The result is an error saying "Bad Request." If the file is a text file and I don't base64_encode, it works fine. Problem results when posting a binary file such as an image.

Anyone know the trick here?

**EDIT 1**

Also problematic is if I encode the text file, it seems to work but of course it's encoded and ends up being junk once downloaded and viewed again (i.e, the text is encoded and doesn't seem to get de-coded by the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems there is no need to use base64_encode. The file_get_contents already puts it into the required format.

Additionally, the problem was because I had the server side config setting for the maxArrayLength too low.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `base64_encode()` should be doing the job.
Are you 100% sure $file contains something? Have you made a dump?

Comment: Yep, done the dump and I see that $file is set. Plus, it works fine with non-binary files...